# Can't create Google contact that populates email address when first name typed

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I'm losing my mind here! Two people I email often are my mom and dad. I want to be able to type "dad" in the to: field and have his email address auto-populate. When I type "mom", her email address is auto-populated. When I type "dad", nothing. Here's what's utterly confusing to me:

The contact name for my mom is "mom". The contact name for my dad is "dad".

To start fresh I deleted all contacts with my dad's email address. I then created a new contact with first name set to "dad" and his email address. No other information.

Gmail still won't auto-populate when I type "dad" in the to: line.

As a test, I created a new contact. The only data I included was a first name "testori" and and a made up "x@gmail" email address, where x is a random string of characters. When I type "testori" in the to: field "x@gmail.com" is auto-populated as I would expect it to be.

My only guess is that somehow having too many duplicate contacts for my dad at one point is causing this and even though I deleted them all and am starting fresh, Google's servers still need time to "catch up" and sort this out.

I'm baffled though. Please help!

Comment: Now it works. It just took about ten minutes of waiting. Perhaps changing, deleting and recreating the same contact caused Google's servers to take more time to make it work properly. I don't know emoji.

Comment: After a day or so gmail reverted to its old ways. Even though I have a contact named "dad" that is only the name "dad" and an email address, google will not autofill or suggest that email address when I type "dad" in the to: field. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know, man, but this is really annoying and I wish they'd code things right. --another Ryan.